# Java SortedMap - TreeMap Key out of Range

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

I'm working on a project where I use a TreeMap as chronological index.

```
SortedMap<Long, String> expiryIndex = new TreeMap<>();
Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
expiryIndex.put(now, null);
```

The aim is to later be able to create TailSet of "older" items without having to iterate. 
However, I'm not getting this far because already at put I get an exception:

```
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key out of range
```

I don't see what I could have done wrong here.

Comment: Please show the code *with the arguments* where you access the `TailSet`

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing any treatment before and/or after your declaration ? I'm running your snippet on my local Eclipse (JDK 8) and it runs just fine.

Comment: I run the code on openjdk 11, it works well

Comment: According to the error you invoked Map.put() on a submap and not the Map itself.   
You can only put elements with key in the bounds of the submap.

Comment: run the code in java 8 is ok,but the TreeMap can throw new IllegalArgumentException("key out of range"),can support more codes?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact this was indeed my fault.

I had a code block further down, where I sliced a tailset out of it. Since these slices are value by reference, the put in the corresponding tailslice was out of bounds, although it was made into the full set. Hence Davidxxx's comment was basically the hint.

Still.. weird. Thanks